# Can I have instructions in each flatmap case? If not, how to increase counter?

Tags: scala, flatmap

I have a `flatmap` that's going through a `Sequence`, and I'm using `case` in order to identify different elements in the `Sequence`, and replace the elements with something else. However, in some of those cases, I also want to increase a counter variable. Can I put an  instruction inside a `case`? It seems that I can't, since what goes inside the `case` is what's going to replace the element of the `Sequence`. Is this possible at all?
Here's the code that I tried, and it didn't work:

```
var location = 0
code.flatMap {
        case Define(label) => Word("")                            // Return an empty Word, don't increase location
        case CodeWord(word) => word; location = location + 4    // Return the Word and increase location by 4
        case Use(label) => Word(Assembler.encodeUnsigned(labelToValue(label))); location = location + 4
                                                                  // Convert label into Seq, then into Word. Increase location.
        case BeqBne(bits, label) =>{ // Are brackets necessary?
            Word(bits ++ encodeUnsigned(labelToValue(label) - (location + 4))); location = location + 4 }
        case _ => require(false, s"Encountered unsupported code $code.");
      }
```

It's important that I update the `location` variable because as you can see, in `case BeqBne(bits, label)` I need to use the current value of `location`. Should I create a function outside of `flatmap` which does all of that stuff and then just call the function and pass the values in each case inside of `flatmap`?
Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: I might be helpful to provide some context for this code. From what I can glean from the above code snippet, I suspect that `flatMap`, or at least the way you're applying it, is not the most natural approach. Maybe I'm being picky, but the combination of `flatMap` with side effects sets off my spidey sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When specifying multiple statements in a block of code the last statement is used as the return value.  So you will need to increase the location variable first and then create the Word result.

E.g., change:

```
case Use(label) => {
  Word(Assembler.encodeUnsigned(labelToValue(label)));
  location = location + 4
}
```

To:

```
case Use(label) => {
  location = location + 4;
  Word(Assembler.encodeUnsigned(labelToValue(label)));
}
```

Or if you need to increment location after creating the result then store the result in a variable:

```
case BeqBne(bits, label) => {
  val result = Word(bits ++ encodeUnsigned(labelToValue(label) - (location + 4)));
  location = location + 4;
  result
}
```